# Select second most recent date from inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    companies.display_name, companies.pay_schedule_id, 
    pay_schedule_periods.schedule_id, 
    pay_schedule_periods.created_at
FROM
    companies
INNER JOIN 
    pay_schedule_periods ON pay_schedule_id = pay_schedule_periods.schedule_id
ORDER BY 
    companies.display_name, pay_schedule_periods.created_at DESC;
```

I get this result :

[image]

How can I select only the second most recent `created_at` date from each unique `display_name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number` to assign a sequence to your dates and apply this before joining, then include as part of your join criteria, such as:

```
select c.display_name, c.pay_schedule_id, psp.schedule_id, psp.created_at
from companies c
join (
  select pay_schedule_id, created_at, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by pay_schedule_id order by created_at desc) rn
  from pay_schedule_periods 
)psp on psp.schedule_id = c.pay_schedule_id and rn = 2
order by c.display_name, psp.created_at desc;
```

You could also apply this using a *lateral join* which would simplify further.